# Replace visible "\n" to real newline character in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bundle of characters that have some real "\n" character:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nn/DC13lNczY/Ugsv7BMX7HfQuXrxinvZcrILX10yJ1e43/lrLRZULI4=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
```

How can I replace these "\n" to real newline character in bash script?

Comment: `new=$(echo -e "$var"); echo "$new"`

Comment: I've tested it and it only convert \n to white space, not new line.

Comment: That is because you said `echo $new` and not `echo "$new"` -- note the quotes around the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
 cat cert | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: sed takes a filename as a command line argument. Check out UUOC.